# iPhone 5 slowly fails to connect to wifi

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

My iPhone 5 running 7.1.1 has stopped connecting to wifi networks.

In the beginning, everything was fine. It seemed like maybe the network in my house was stretched a little thin, and I had trouble connecting at one end of the house. So did all of our other devices, so I thought nothing of it.

Then I moved to a house where I don't have access to the wifi controls. My phone began to drop the connection periodically, but I could usually get back in after a few tries. I blamed it on my stepdad's weird network settings that I couldn't access. Until I stopped being able to get in at all. No matter what, I got the "Unable to join the network "[our network]"" dialog and "Failed to join ["ournetwork"]".

I was still blaming it on my stepdad (because that's what stepdads are for) when I realized I couldn't connect to any of the public wifi networks in places I visit periodically (and have successfully connected to before).

I have restarted my iPhone and reset its network settings. This morning I did a full backup and restore, having read around the internet that that fixed the problem for many. During the iOS setup process, I was asked to enter a password for a nearby wifi network. Nada. Couldn't get in.

It's like my iPhone 5 just slowly forgot how to wifi. How do I remind it?

> #### Update!

I took my phone to the Genius Bar, where an Apple employee ran all the diagnostics and looked into a bunch of histories. He found that TCCService had been crashing periodically, and did a Reset All Settings (as opposed to Reset Network Settings, which I'd already done).

It seems to have helped a little bit, but it remains to be seen whether this has fixed the problem completely.

> #### Long-awaited update

Profiles were to blame.

I have a couple of different custom profiles on my phone because I work with a few beta apps. Removing obsolete profiles fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If re-setting your network connections didn't help, it could be a hardware problem.

Depending on when it was made, it could be that your WiFi chip inside the phone has pulled  (or, rather, is in the process *of* pulling) off of the circuit board. Late 4S models also had this problem, and here's how it manifests (progressively):

- Very slow speeds / drops connection to the network intermittently
- Stops seeing most (or all) networks, but the WiFi button still works, it's not grayed out
- Can't turn WiFi on at all, the button is grayed out in the settings menu - but the WiFi button in the control center *might* appear to work.

If your phone is under warranty, then take it to an Apple store and have them replace it. Believe it or not, the repair *is* quite easy, so if it's out of warranty and you know of a place that fixes phones, they've probably got some spare chips and won't charge too much. Apparently, it's a manufacturing defect, so a repaired phone fixed by someone that knows their stuff could last quite some time.

This has only been a problem with certain 4S and 5 models, you'll see a bunch of people reporting it if you search for something like "iPhone in freezer" - because (believe it or not), putting your phone in a Ziplock and then freezing it for a few minutes has been known to fix the problem for a short time (though I don't recommend doing this).

AFAIK, this isn't an issue with 5C, 5S or recently (as in the last year) manufactured iPhone 5 units. Could be a good opportunity to upgrade, even if you manage to get it fixed.